# What was the purpose of the emboldened text below in [class.copy]/12 in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

[class.copy]/12 in C++14:

A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided, **its parameter-type-list is equivalent
to the parameter-type-list of an implicit declaration**, and if

- (12.1) — class X has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base
  classes (10.1), and
- (12.2) — class X has no non-static data members    of
  volatile-qualified type, and
- (12.3) — the constructor selected to    copy/move each direct base
  class subobject is trivial, and
- (12.4) —    for each non-static data member of X that is of class
  type (or array    thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move
  that member is    trivial;

otherwise the copy/move constructor is non-trivial.

I can see that the sentence above was erased in N4606, but I couldn't find anything in [C++ Standard Core Language Active Issues, Revision 96](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html) to justify its removal from C++14.

Comment: I wonder if it was added because the implicit copy constructor could have the form `X::X(const X&)` or `X::X(X&)`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but if it is not user-provided, how could its parameter list differ from the implicit one ? I think that "not user-provided" was meant to replace it, but it slipped by.

Answer (score 6):

This is a result of [CWG 2171](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2171). The removed text only changes the meaning in one case:

```
struct X {
    X(X& ) = default; // not user-provided
                      // parameter-type-list differs from implicit declaration's X const&
                      // wasn't trivial before, is trivial now
};
```

But whether or not this copy constructor is trivial is a separate question of whether or not it is actually invokable, so the original text was deemed inconsistent with the usual intent of the standard and hence removed.

Comment: `parameter-type-list differs from implicit declaration's X const&` But according to [class.copy]/8, there are two implicit declarations for the copy constructor: X(const X&) and X(X&).

Comment: @Alexander That's not what that bullet says. There is only ever one implicit declaration for the copy constructor, and for my type above it would be `X(X const&)`.

Comment: Also, [class.copy]/8 doesn't seem to be clear on what is the implicit declaration for the copy ctor for an empty class, like `struct X{};`.

Comment: @Alexander "all of" for an empty sequence is true.

Comment: `There is only ever one implicit declaration for the copy constructor, and for my type above it would be X(X const&)`. This is obviously wrong, as this doesn't compile: `struct A { A(A&) = default; A(){} }; const A a; A b = a;`.

Comment: @Alexander Why would you expect it to compile? You provided a copy constructor, so there is no implicitly declared one. Your copy constructor can't take a `const A`.

Comment: You provided a copy-constructor yourself in your snippet above. Then your statement in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131127/what-was-the-purpose-of-the-emboldened-text-below-in-class-copy-12-in-c14#comment67533987_40131352) above cannot be correct.

Comment: @Alexander s/would be/would have been.